# how to get the selected radio buttons value

Tags: jquery

I have a simple from with 2 radio buttons and I need to get their values if they are checked.

```
<form class="descriptions" id="collection" method="post" action="">
    <table width="200">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Collection</label>
                <input type="radio" value="collection" name="collection" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>Delivery</label>
                <input type="radio" value="delivery" name="collection" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>


<script>
    var delivery = "";
    delivery = $('input:radio:checked').val();
    if (delivery == 'delivery') {
        meal_deal7 = 11.49;
    } else {
        meal_deal7 = 9.99
    }
</script>
```

the value of meal_deal7 is always 9.99,
am I doing sth wrong.

thanks

Comment: try debugging the delivery variable. Either `console.log(delivery)` or `alert(delivery)`. That way, you'll see what delivery holds. If it's empty all the time, then you're doing something wrong with your selector (should be fine, though)...

Comment: Your code works just fine for me. Try debugging the code.

Comment: It works for me. The issue must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to have your code in an event handler attached to each of the radio buttons so that the value of `delivery` variable is updated each time a radio button is clicked/checked

**[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/asuka)** - add **/edit** to see the code and play with the example.

The code

```
 $("input:radio[name='collection']").click(function() {
     var delivery = $("input:radio[name='collection']:checked").val();

     if(delivery == 'delivery') {
         meal_deal7 = 11.49;
     }
     else {
         meal_deal7 = 9.99
     }
 });
```

I'd be tempted to use a CSS class to identify the radiobuttons too

Answer (score 1):

Look at the following example courtesy this [link](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/finding_the_value_of_a_radio_button.php3)
and make the necessary changes to your form;

```
<form name="orderform">
Which one is your favorite?<br>
<input type="radio" name="music" value="Rock" 
checked="checked"> Rock<br>
<input type="radio" name="music" value="Reggae"> Reggae<br>
<input type="radio" name="music" value="Pop"> Pop<br>
<input type="radio" name="music" value="Rap"> Rap<br>
<input type="radio" name="music" value="Metal"> Metal<br>
<input type="submit" onclick="get_radio_value()">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's javascript, I wanted to do it with jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript to get the value

```
var elemArray=document.getElementsByName('collection');
var value="";
if(elemArray.length>0){
for(var i=0;i<elemArray.length;i++){
if(elemArray.checked==true){
value=elemArray.value;
}
}
}else{
if(elemArray.checked==true){
value=elemArray.value;
}
}
```